# SharePoint workflow performance issues: Due to Heavy load

Tags: sharepoint, caching, workflow, email-notifications

I'm running a demo in a couple days of a new Vacation Request workflow I created. The code runs great however the email notifications are not being sent out immediately due to this error message:

Note: Due to heavy load, the latest workflow operation has been queued. It will attempt to 
resume at a later time.

I have tried everything including:

- Increase throttle size
- Increase Batch size
- Time out
- Workflow interval
- Bump up App / Web servers to 16GB
- Clear SP Cache
- Force running the Workflow timer job in Central Admin

Any suggestions? Should I try removing the App server from the farm?

Comment: Is there a repetition in the workflow. This happens when there is a infinite loop in the workflow. All the workflow tasks gets Queued.